# Generating htpasswd entry using R

Tags: r, openssl, .htpasswd

Is there a way to generate a `htpasswd` entry using R, ie, without using the `htpasswd` utility itself?

According to [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html),

> `htpasswd` encrypts passwords using either bcrypt, a version of MD5 modified for Apache, SHA1, or the system's `crypt()` routine. Files managed by `htpasswd` may contain a mixture of different encoding types of passwords; some user records may have bcrypt or MD5-encrypted passwords while others in the same file may have passwords encrypted with `crypt()`.

I tried using either `openssl::md5` or `digest::digest`, but they don't seem to be producing anything I can recognise.

Here's some sample output using `htpasswd` on Ubuntu. The result changes each time, presumably because there is a salt being used. The hash doesn't look like it's base64-encoded either.

```
hongo@hongsdev:~$ echo bar | htpasswd -n -i foo
foo:$apr1$ArTUhiJz$/qjciBNKHEWwpXBof75rb.

hongo@hongsdev:~$ echo bar | htpasswd -n -i foo
foo:$apr1$pZxmtIam$VkfMvV2qR4NBkPm3MKcJ/.

hongo@hongsdev:~$ echo bar | htpasswd -n -i foo
foo:$apr1$IFM43G9p$UkQB9QSONrwD74WpXlP7f/
```

Some attempts using `openssl::md5` and `digest::digest`:

```
r$> openssl::md5("bar")
[1] "37b51d194a7513e45b56f6524f2d51f2"

r$> digest::digest("bar", algo="md5")
[1] "cbd2100992f98ebf9169448cf98f63a5"

r$> openssl::base64_encode(openssl::md5("bar"))
[1] "MzdiNTFkMTk0YTc1MTNlNDViNTZmNjUyNGYyZDUxZjI="
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this....

The [bcrypt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bcrypt/index.html) package provides an R interface to the blowfish password hashing algorithm, and can be used to generate a suitable file. There don't seem to be packages for the other algorithms, but this one works.

```
library(bcrypt)

user_list <- list(
    c("user1", "password1")
)
user_str <- sapply(user_list, function(x) paste(x[1], hashpw(x[2]), sep=":"))
writeLines(user_str, "auth")
```